# Is Audio Type Selection (Headset, Default, Speaker) Supported in React Native Agora for Audio Implementation?

Tags: reactjs, native, agora

What are the available audio input options in React Native Agora for implementing audio functionality?

Can you specify if React Native Agora provides the option to select the audio type, such as headset, default, or speaker, during audio implementation?

engine?.enableLocalAudio(true);
engine?.muteLocalAudioStream(!isMuted);